# String concatenation in c, not using function

Tags: c, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate strings not using function in Dev-C++ compiler. So my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

char string1[] = "water", string2[] = "melon";
int i=0,j=0;

while(i++, string1[i] != 0);
for(j=0;string2[j] !=0; i++){

    string1[i] = string2[j];
    j++;
}



printf("%s",string1);

getch();
return 0;
```

}

The output i get is: watermelp. Where's the problem?

Note: I couldn't use `*string1` and `*string2` instead of `string1[]` and `string2[]`. As i have to use `const` (because of Wwrite-strings warning) while declaring them. And this gives an error while concatenating as an assignment of read-only location. Is there any solution of it?

Comment: There are much better free compilers than Turbo C nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the symptoms of undefined behavior. You are writing over memory that you are not supposed to.

When you use:

```
char string1[] = "water", string2[] = "melon";
```

`string1` and `string2` have enough memory to hold `"water"` and `"melon"`, respectively.

Use

```
char string1[100] = "water", string2[] = "melon";
```

With that, `string1` will have enough memory to hold `"watermelon"`.

**Suggestion for improvement:**

Instead of

```
while(i++, string1[i] != 0);
```

Use

```
while ( string1[i] != 0 ) i++;
```

The second form is not only more readable, it also avoids an error.
The first form will be wrong if `string1` is an empty string.

Comment: also need to add the null character at end

Comment: It worked. But i still can't understand how it caused problem. Please define it.

Comment: @FechangFuchang, Undefined Behavior, is by definition, undefined. It is futile to try to make sense of it.